# Nuxt 3: Prevent Retrying Requests with useFetch, useAsyncData and useLazyFetch on Status 500 or 429

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, fetch, nuxt3

I'm encountering an issue in my Nuxt 3 application where requests are being retried automatically when they fail with a status code of 500 or 429. This behavior is unexpected, and I haven't been able to find a way of preventing this.

I haven't attempted any specific solutions yet because, despite thorough research, I haven't found documentation or resources addressing how to prevent the automatic retry of requests with status codes 500 or 429 in Nuxt 3. My initial focus has been on reviewing the official documentation and community forums.

If you have any suggestions or insights on how to address this issue, your input would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, if there are any specific sections in the documentation that I might have overlooked, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I discovered that adding the retry: 0 option to the fetch configuration when using the useFetch function in Nuxt 3 effectively prevents automatic request retries.

The retry option in the fetch configuration controls the number of retries for a failed request. By setting it to 0, we instruct the fetch mechanism not to retry the request in case of failure, thus circumventing the default behavior that might automatically retry requests on certain HTTP status codes (such as 500 or 429).

Here's an example of how this solution is implemented in the code:

```
async function createQuote(body: QuotePayload) {
   const { data: response, error } = await useFetch<DataMessage<Quote>>(
      `api/quotes`,
      {
         baseURL: store_user.url_old_project,
         body: body,
         headers: store_user.auth_header,
         key: `createQuote ${Date.now()}`,
         method: 'POST',
         retry: 0,
      },
   )

   return { error, response }
}
```

While this solution works on a per-request basis, I'm currently exploring whether there is a way to configure this behavior globally in the Nuxt project settings or configuration options. If anyone has insights on a global configuration for disabling retries, please feel free to share!!